# android facebook sdk 3.14.1 posting on friend's wall

Tags: android, facebook

I used facebook-sdk 3.14.1 for android to post some content on friend's wall. 
When i try to post on my wall using the WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder class, it works perfectlly. But when i want to post something on friend's wall, using WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(context, session) and calling the method setTo(friendID) on it, it gives me the next error: "This dialog has been passed a bad parameter."

Here is my code:

```
public static void postToFriendWall(Activity activity, String message, String facebookID)
{
    Session session=Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session!=null)
    {
        Bundle _postParameter=new Bundle();
        _postParameter.putString("to", facebookID);
        _postParameter.putString("name", message);
        _postParameter.putString("link", "http://www.link.com");
        _postParameter.putString("picture", "http://www.link.com/images/preview.png");
        _postParameter.putString("description", activity.getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_share));

        WebDialog dialog=(new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity, session, _postParameter)).build();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

I tried to capture the url which has been generated and loaded in the webview, and paste in a normal browser, it gives me the same error message, but when I remove the "to=friendID" from the URL, it perfectlly works but the post is in my own wall.
I was also surprised seeing it works with the iOS version for the facebook-sdk.
Can anyone help me for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Share Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkapi

Comment: I've already tried to use it but it doesn't specify how to post on friend wall. Request request = new Request(session, facebookID+"/feed", _postParameter, HttpMethod.POST, callback); doesn't work

Comment: The share dialog just let the user share it on their wall. If you want to send a message you can use the send dialog. Don't post on other peoples wall